# In VS Code, the terminal doesn't show an option for the Ubuntu 20.04 shell

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-20.04, wsl-2

I open VSCode from WSL/Ubuntu with the command `code .`.

In the terminal dropdown, I'm looking for the Ubuntu (WSL) shell, but it's not there
.
[image: Screenshot of terminal dropdown]

Any guidance on how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `bash` and `tmux` will launch terminals for your WSL Ubuntu instance.  It apparently picks up the list of available shells from your `/etc/shells` (plus the JavaScript debug terminal, of course).
you can see the full list from `/etc/shells` if you run the *"Terminal: Select Default Profile"* command from the VSCode Command Palette.

You can verify that you are in your WSL instance by launching either the `bash` or `tmux` profiles, then running:

```
echo $WSL_DISTRO_NAME
```

I'd have to look at the VSCode or "Remote - WSL" extension source to see for sure, but I'm guessing there's a hard-coded list of "common" shells that it will display as the default.  With `fish` installed on my system, it is also in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to first check if it is an option in the Terminal application. It may not show in VSCode until it is started in Terminal first, where it prompts you to setup a WSL username and password.